# MS ACCESS SQL Consolidate multiple Rows into one, maintain columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to Summarize the total number of classes taught by each instructor for a course. Each class can have up to 4 instructors listed.

I am part way to a solution but I am hung up. I have already done a count of the class taught by each instructor# (INS), in each position (Instructor 1-4), But I can't return it all in one line for each instructor.  I'm doing this in MS ACCESS, but if someone can give me a SQL solution and not VBA that would be great.

My Code:

```
SELECT Instructor1 AS INS
, SUM (IIF(Instructor1 > 0,1,0)) AS [Instructor 1]
,"" AS [INSTRUCTOR 2],"" AS [INSTRUCTOR 3],"" AS [INSTRUCTOR 4]
FROM (Select DISTINCT CourseDate, [Course Completion].[ClassNumber], 
Instructor1,  Instructor2,  Instructor3,  Instructor4 FROM [Course 
Completion] )  AS CLASSES 
WHERE YEAR(CourseDate) = [ENTER YEAR]
Group by Instructor1
UNION.....
```

I do that 4 times with the unions to pull instructors from each of the instructor positions.

What I have:

```
INS    Instructor 1   INSTRUCTOR 2    INSTRUCTOR 3  INSTRUCTOR 4
23885                      1        
23885       1           
27117                      3        
27117       4           
27475       1   
27721                      12       
27721       10          
27748                                      2    
27748                       4       
27748        8          
27832                                       2   
27832                       3       
27832        3
```

what I want is this:

```
INS Instructor 1    INSTRUCTOR 2    INSTRUCTOR 3    INSTRUCTOR 4
23885   1                 1     
27117   4                 3     
27475   1
27721   10                12        
27748   8                 4             2   
27832   3                 3             2
```

Comment: Is  your expect result ID `27475` correct ?

Comment: Looks like a simple aggregate GROUP BY query. I suspect the output example isn't correct for 27475 and 27721.

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up the lines when I was condensing it to the desired format.